# Dojo candlestick chart - update series with json

Tags: charts, dojo

I am using the Dojo toolkit to create a candlestick chart.  I have a number of different series of data by year that a user will be able to click a button to select the year of data and the candlestick chart will be updated.  I have been able to do this successfully when I have the data directly in the code:

```
makeCharts = function() {

  series2012 =  [
        {open: 477, close: 471.5, high: 477,  low:  471.5,  mid:  474.2,  tooltip:"Orange  <br />Rate: 474.2"},
        {open: 524.5, close: 442.1, high: 524.5,  low: 442.1,  mid:  481.7,  tooltip:"Blue <br />Rate: 481.7"},etc.......
  series2011 =  [
        {open: 600, close: 481.5, high: 600,  low:  481.5,  mid:  490.2,  tooltip:"Orange  <br />Rate: 490.2"},
        {open: 554.5, close: 412.1, high: 554.5,  low: 412.1,  mid:  481.7,  tooltip:"Blue <br />Rate: 481.7"},etc.......
```

To add the series:

```
chart1.addSeries("Series 1", series2012,{stroke: {color:"#003399"}, fill: "#3399cc"});
```

And then to update the series with a button click:

```
<button onclick="chart1.updateSeries('Series 1', series2011);chart1.render();">2011</button>
```

What I would really like to do is to query the data from an external json file.  I have been able to do this when adding the series, but not to update it. (See the question marks in the html - this is where I am unsure of what to enter):

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    href="https://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    #charts {clear: both;margin-bottom: 50px;}
    .chart-area {float: left;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:  450px;height: 350px;margin: 3px;}
    .chart {width:  450px;height: 300px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");        
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip"); 
dojo.require("dojox.charting.plot2d.Candlesticks");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.DataSeries");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Shake");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
     store4 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
     url: "candle_update1.json"});

makeCharts = function(){ 
  chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("candleChart");
  chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "Candlesticks", gap: 2, minBarSize: 5, maxBarSize: 10});
  chart1.addAxis("x", {              
    natural: true,          
    majorLabels: true,      
    includeZero: false, 
    majorTickStep: 1,
    majorTick: {
    stroke: "black",
    length: 5
  },
  fixUpper:"major",
  stroke: "black",

  labels: [          
    {value: 1,  text: "Orange"},
    {value: 2,  text: "Red"},
    {value: 3,  text: "Blue"},
    {value: 4,  text: "Black"},
    {value: 5,  text: "Yellow"},
    {value: 6,  text: "White"},
    {value: 7,  text: "Green"},
    {value: 8,  text: "Purple"},
    {value: 9,  text: "Brown"}
  ],rotation:-45         
  });

    chart1.addAxis("y", {   
      vertical: true,
      leftBottom: true,
      includeZero: true,
      majorLabels: true,
      fixUpper: "major",
      fixed: true,
      max: 800
    });

 chart1.addSeries("Series 1", new dojox.charting.DataSeries(
  store4, {query: {series: 2012}}, {open: "open", close: "close", high: "high", low: "low", mid: "mid", tooltip: "tooltip"}));

    var anim2 = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, "default");
    var anim1a = new dojox.charting.action2d.Shake(chart1, "default");
};
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    makeCharts();
});
});   
</script>
</head>
<body class="soria">
    <h1>Dojo Candlesticks update test</h1>
    <div id="charts">
      <div class="chart-area">
        <div id="candleChart" class="chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Select years:</strong></span>
    <span id="btn">
      <button onclick="chart1.updateSeries('Series 1', ?????????);chart1.render();">2012</button> 
      <button onclick="chart1.updateSeries('series1', ????????);chart1.render();">2011</button> 
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

The external json file (candle_update1.json):

> {"identifier":"id",
>   "label":"county",
>   "items":[ 
>   {"county":"Orange","id":"1","series":2012,"open":477,"close":471.5,"high":477,"low":471.5,"mid":474.2,"tooltip":"Orange
> rate:474.2"},
>   {"county":"Blue","id":"2","series":2012,"open":524.5,"close":442.1,"high":524.5,"low":442.1,"mid":481.7,"tooltip":"Blue
> rate:481.7"},
>   {"county":"Red","id":"3","series":2012,"open":508.1,"close":481,"high":508.1,"low":481,"mid":494.4,"tooltip":"Red
> rate:494.4"},
>   {"county":"Black","id":"4","series":2012,"open":503.2,"close":439.3,"high":503.2,"low":439.3,"mid":470.4,"tooltip":"Black
> rate:470.4"},
>   {"county":"Yellow","id":"5","series":2012,"open":492.1,"close":430.1,"high":492.1,"low":430.1,"mid":460.3,"tooltip":"Yellow
> rate:460.3"},
>   {"county":"White","id":"6","series":2012,"open":495.5,"close":425.5,"high":495.5,"low":425.5,"mid":459.6,"tooltip":"White
> rate:459.6"},
>   {"county":"Green","id":"7","series":2012,"open":550.9,"close":414.4,"high":550.9,"low":414.4,"mid":478.2,"tooltip":"Green
> rate:478.2"},
>   {"county":"Purple","id":"8","series":2012,"open":484.8,"close":431.5,"high":484.8,"low":431.5,"mid":457.6,"tooltip":"Purple
> rate:457.6"},
>   {"county":"Brown","id":"9","series":2012,"open":486.6,"close":419.6,"high":486.6,"low":419.6,"mid":452.1,"tooltip":"Brown
> rate:452.1"},
>   {"county":"Orange","id":"1a","series":2011,"open":600,"close":481.5,"high":600,"low":481.5,"mid":490.2,"tooltip":"Orange
> rate:450.2"},
>   {"county":"Blue","id":"2a","series":2011,"open":554.5,"close":412.1,"high":554.5,"low":412.1,"mid":451.7,"tooltip":"Blue
> rate:451.7"},
>   {"county":"Red","id":"3a","series":2011,"open":608.1,"close":481,"high":608.1,"low":481,"mid":594.4,"tooltip":"Red
> rate:474.4"},
>   {"county":"Black","id":"4a","series":2011,"open":703.2,"close":409.3,"high":703.2,"low":409.3,"mid":470.4,"tooltip":"Black
> rate:470.4"},
>   {"county":"Yellow","id":"5a","series":2011,"open":392.1,"close":230.1,"high":392.1,"low":230.1,"mid":260.3,"tooltip":"Yellow
> rate:260.3"},
>   {"county":"White","id":"6a","series":2011,"open":495.5,"close":425.5,"high":495.5,"low":425.5,"mid":459.6,"tooltip":"White
> rate:459.6"},
>   {"county":"Green","id":"7a","series":2011,"open":750.9,"close":414.4,"high":750.9,"low":414.4,"mid":478.2,"tooltip":"Green
> rate:478.2"},
>   {"county":"Purple","id":"8a","series":2011,"open":584.8,"close":431.5,"high":584.8,"low":431.5,"mid":457.6,"tooltip":"Purple
> rate:457.6"},
>   {"county":"Brown","id":"9a","series":2011,"open":786.6,"close":319.6,"high":786.6,"low":319.6,"mid":452.1,"tooltip":"Brown
> rate:452.1"}

]}

So, I have been struggling how to update the series.  How should the data array part of updateseries be formatted or written to grab the correct series of data?

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be going with a store and Observable object. This way data updates when store updates.

```
// Initial data
var data = [
    // This information, presumably, would come from a database or web service
    // Note that the values for site are either 1 or 2
    { id: 1, value: 20, site: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 16, site: 1 },
    { id: 3, value: 11, site: 1 },
    { id: 4, value: 18, site: 1 },
    { id: 5, value: 26, site: 1 },
    { id: 6, value: 19, site: 2 },
    { id: 7, value: 20, site: 2 },
    { id: 8, value: 28, site: 2 },
    { id: 9, value: 12, site: 2 },
    { id: 10, value: 4, site: 2 }
];

// Create the data store
// Store information in a data store on the client side
var store = dojo.store.Observable(new dojo.store.Memory({
    data: {
        identifier: "id",
        label: "Users Online",
        items: data
    }
}));
```

You can load your store from external file via XHR

And this is how you'd get your series set

```
// Adds a StoreSeries to the y axis, queries for all site 1 items
chart.addSeries("y", new dojox.charting.StoreSeries(store, { query: { site: 1 } }, "value"));
```

Comment: To read the documentation, I can go to dojo's site... I didn't came here for some copy&paste...